Why ttf-mscorefonts-installer can't install Microsoft's Chinese fonts?
There are some Chinese fonts in windows:
FangSong，仿宋
KaiTi，楷体
Microsoft YaHei，微软雅黑
SimSun，宋体

Now install the installer:
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer  
sudo fc-cache -fv

Why no FangSong,KaiTi,Microsoft YaHei,SimSun in my os?
fc-list | grep  -i  FangSong
fc-list | grep  -i  KaiTi
fc-list | grep  -i  Microsoft YaHei
fc-list | grep  -i  SimSun

Nothing as the above command's output,why?

Perhaps because when MS released the mscorefont, they did not include those Chinese fonts. And since MS has since retracted the openness of these fonts, they have not been updated with others.
